# Responsive button appearing to be two buttons on :hover

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I've tried to make a form responsive.

In doing so if I now **hover over the submit button two buttons seem to appear?**

[Example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d6zpg0ge/4/)

Example image:

[image]

Code:

```
.loudbutton:hover { cursor:pointer;
width: 90%;
height: 40%;
background-image: url('http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/submit-button-2015-light-2.jpg');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is it's repeating the image when the image isn't big enough to fill the whole element.

Add `background-size: 100% 100%` to get it to fill the button and not repeat:

```
.loudbutton:hover { cursor:pointer;
    width: 90%;
    height: 40%;
    background-image: url('http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/submit-button-2015-light-2.jpg');
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

That said, as Denis pointed out, this kind of image can be easily done with CSS so that you wouldn't need an image file at all. [Updated Fiddle without the image](https://jsfiddle.net/d6zpg0ge/11/).

Answer (score 0):

.loudbutton:hover { cursor:pointer;
url('http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/submit-button-2015-light-2.jpg') cover;
}

Answer (score 0):

The background image setted in hover is not as wide as the button.
Instead of using a background image, you can use the CSS to achieve the same result without using an image, saving http requests.

Comment: Thanks, there was a reason I did this but I can't remember and an on:hover background image seems to work so I think this is probably the easiest solution!

Answer (score 0):

change css to

```
.loudbutton:hover {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```